# MVC Url relative to variable ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, relative-path

Reasonably new to MVC. My problem is that I have a controller that has 3 different ActionResult's which are called depending on an enum. 
All three action results return the same view but with different lists as the views model. In the view the user should be able to click on an item in the list and view the details based on the ID of the item.
e.g. Site/Facilities/Libraries returns the list of libraries, Site/Facilities/Libraries/1 returns the details. This works fine when you enter the full path but on the View itself clicking the anchor

```
<a href="@item.ID">@item.Name</a>
```

on an item in the list returns the Url Site/Facilities/1 instead of Site/Facilities/Libraries/1. I cant use an ActionLink as the Action to call is dynamic. I know this could be solved by creating a different View for each type but I wondered if there might be another way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such code (a javascript trick):

```
<a href="" onclick="window.location = window.location + @item.ID">@item.Name</a>
```

Or, if you want to use **href** property, you can use such code:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Facilities", ViewData("ActionName"), new {id = item.ID}) %>
```

(In that case you have to specify ViewData("ActionName") in controller).

Comment: Ive tried the second option and its so simple Im ashamed I didnt think of it. It ideally needs to work without Javascript as it is for mobile development and not all phones have javascript available. The second option is great though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you change it so that you only have one Action, but it takes an argument instead, and depending on the argument you push different lists to the View (perhaps using 3 different "helper-functions" instead). That's at least how I would implement what you are describing!

Good luck!

Comment: Thats how I originally implemented it but if someone was to copy the url (or bookmark it) of the list and then use it again it wouldn't take an argument and would fail.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be copied and/or bookmarked? Since the argument is included in the URL it should come along too! (Unless the user deletes that part, but that's sort of their problem isn't it? ^^) With some fancy routing you'd have perfectly fine URLs. But good that you found an answer you're happy with :)